How to avoid installing all `bin` files with `cargo install`?
cargo install installs all files in src/bin folder.
I have

src/bin/cli.rs
src/bin/dev.rs

Even if I add
[[bin]]
name = "cli"
path = "src/bin/cli.rs"

dev is stilled installed when I run cargo install.

Use cargo install --bin cli.
See cargo install - The Cargo Book.
